# What's the minimal set of sequence "primitives" required for any sequence computations?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, scheme

I am writing a Scheme-like in interpreter. It seems natural that the Scheme-like interpreter ought to work well with any object that implements IEnumerable.

The interpreter does not allow for mutation - no functions with side effects are exposed.

Because IEnumerable is not cloneable, (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807991/why-cant-ienumerators-be-cloned) ), I can't implement iteration over the list efficiently using car and cdr.

In order to allow any "higher order" stuff to be efficient then, I've had to implement some primitives as C# builtins for the interpreter.

So far I have implemented the following "primitives" as C# builtin functions:

1. filter
2. map (the full map, not just mapcar)
3. foldr

But I suspect, for example, that I could probably implement "filter" using a combination of map and foldr.

What is the minimal set of primitives I would need to expose as "builtins" such that I can implement any other functionality over IEnumerable instances without excess runtime or space costs, and without having to introduce mutation?

Comment: Just an observation. I used to use IEnumerable for lists too, but as soon as you need improper lists, the whole thing falls flat. I found it better just to create a Cons class and use it like it is used in Scheme.  This does not say that your Cons cannot be IEnumerable, just do not rely on it being a proper list.

Comment: Enumerable can be 'cloned' fast. Just use select and pass in the identity function for a selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the functions are already there for you in the System.Linq namespace.

1. filter = Where
2. map = Select
3. fold/reduce = Aggregate (foldr = Reverse then Aggregate)

You will find many more. Eg

SelectMany = map + map + flatten
GroupBy = partition

remq and friends can be done in terms of filter.

**Update**

These obviously only take 1 single list argument, unlike the normal Scheme definitions.

Comment: ah but couldn't I implement filter in terms of map and fold?...

I suppose... need a way of constructing IEnumerables

Comment: You could, but why?  :)  It will be ugly!

Answer (score 2):

You don't strictly need `map` to be a primitive as you can define it in terms of `foldr`.

Example (in Haskell):

```
map f = foldr (\a b->f a:b) []
```

This is really `mapcar` not `map`, but full `map` is difficult to express in Haskell as `apply` is not available.

More complete example (in Scheme):

```
(define (mapcar f l)
  (foldr (lambda (x t) (cons (f x) t)) ‛() l))

(define (heads ls) (mapcar car ls))

(define (tails ls) (mapcar cdr ls))

(define (any-null? ls) (foldr or? ﹟f (mapcar null? ls)))

(define (map f . ls)
  (if (any-null? ls)
      ‛()
      (cons (apply f (heads ls)) (apply map f (tails ls)))))
```

And if you don't have `car` and `cdr` there are other ways to define them, e.g. if you have closures & variables in your language:

```
(define (car a) (foldr (lambda (x y) x) ﹟f a))

(define (cdr a)
  (let ((prev ‛())
        (tmp #f))
    (foldr (lambda (h t) (set! tmp (cons h t)) (set! prev t) tmp)
           ‛()
           a)
    prev))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what functionality you are aiming for with your sequence computations, but a concat operation (i.e. flatten nested sequences) might be very useful too. Take a look at how Haskell's list comprehensions are desugared to see why.

Comment: to flatten *nested* sequence, .NET has SelectMany